# Openshift :Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

i'm getting this error i also created rbac.yaml. But it require admin permission. is it possible to apply rbac.yaml without admin role ??

```
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: hazelcast-rbac
subjects:
  name: default-cluster
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, only cluster admin can create `ClusterRoleBinding`. If you are project admin, please create `RoleBinding` instead.

To check if you can create `rolebinding`:

```
oc adm policy who-can create rolebinding
```

Comment: now i'm getting Failure executing: GET at: https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/some-arun/endpoints/some-service . Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. endpoints \"some-service\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:some-arun:default\" cannot get endpoints in the namespace \"some-arun\": User

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#use-the-default-service-account-to-access-the-api-server